# Cannot get class data in box2d collision callback

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm building a simple 2D game in C++ and am using Box2D for collision detection.

I have an `Entity` class from which an `Enemy` and `Bullet` class is derived, and an `EnemySquare` class is derived from the `Enemy` class.

I'm trying to detect collisions between the EnemySquare class and the `Bullet` class (will have more collision combinations to process later in development). To do this I have created a `CollisionManager` class deriving from the Box2D class `b2ContactListener` which handles the collision callbacks.

Each `Entity` instance has a private variable `m_collisionObjectType` which is an `enum class` of object types (shown below).

In the `BeginContact()` callback, I'm trying to cast the box2d fixture's user data to the correct class type so I can apply damage, mark bullets for removal etc.

(non-relevant code removed for simplicity)

Object Type Enum:

```
enum class COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE {BULLET, ENEMY, PLAYER};
```

Entity class

.h

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    ~Entity();

    COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE getCollisionObjectType() { return m_collisionObjectType; }

protected:

    b2Body* m_body = nullptr;
    b2Fixture* m_fixtures[3];
    COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE m_collisionObjectType;

};
```

Enemy Class

.h

```
class Enemy : public Entity
{
public:
    Enemy();
    ~Enemy();
    virtual void init(glm::vec2 position, float health, float speed, Player* player, b2World* physicsWorld) = 0;
    virtual void update(float deltaTime) = 0;

protected:

    float m_health;
    float m_speed;
    Player* m_playerTarget;

};
```

Enemy Square Class

.h

```
class EnemySquare : public Enemy
{
public:
    EnemySquare();
    ~EnemySquare();

    void init(glm::vec2 position, float health, float speed, Player* player, b2World* physicsWorld) override;
    void update(float deltaTime) override;

};
```

.cpp

```
void EnemySquare::init(glm::vec2 position, float health, float speed, Player * player, b2World* physicsWorld) {

    // init physics body
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(m_position.x, m_position.y);
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = false;
    bodyDef.angle = 0;
    bodyDef.userData = this;
    m_body = physicsWorld->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // init physics fixtures
    b2PolygonShape squareShape;
    squareShape.SetAsBox(m_width * 0.5f, m_height * 0.5f);
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &squareShape;
    m_fixtures[0] = m_body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

}
```

Bullet Class

.h

```
class Bullet : public Entity
{
public:
    Bullet(
        b2World* world,
        glm::vec2 startPosition,
        glm::vec2 direction,
        Tempest::glTexture texture,
        float width,
        float height,
        float damage,
        float speed,
        float range
    );
    ~Bullet();

    // methods are unrelated

private:
    // private variables are unrelated

};
```

.cpp

```
Bullet::Bullet(
    b2World* world,
    glm::vec2 startPosition,
    glm::vec2 direction,
    Tempest::glTexture texture,
    float width,
    float height,
    float damage,
    float speed,
    float range
) {

    // Make the body
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(m_position.x, m_position.y);
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
    bodyDef.angle = 0;
    bodyDef.userData = this;
    m_body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Create the box
    b2PolygonShape boxShape;
    boxShape.SetAsBox(m_height * 0.4f, m_width * 0.5f);

    b2FixtureDef boxDef;
    boxDef.shape = &boxShape;
    m_fixtures[0] = m_body->CreateFixture(&boxDef);

    m_collided = false;

    m_collisionObjectType = COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE::BULLET;

}
```

In my the `CollisionManager` class I'm trying to retrieve the colliding fixture's userData (which is a void*) then cast it to an `Entity*` to call the `getCollisionObjectType()` method. When I know what type of entity I'm dealing with I then want to cast it to the correct object type and do things like apply damage, mark bullets for removal etc. Code below:

```
void CollisionManager::BeginContact(b2Contact * contact) {

    void* fixtureABodyData = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
    void* fixtureBBodyData = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
    if (fixtureABodyData && fixtureBBodyData) {
        Entity* fixtureAData = static_cast<Entity*>(fixtureABodyData);
        Entity* fixtureBData = static_cast<Entity*>(fixtureBBodyData);
        if (fixtureAData->getCollisionObjectType() == COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE::BULLET) {
            std::cout << "A BULLET" << std::endl;
        }
        if (fixtureBData->getCollisionObjectType() == COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE::BULLET) {
            std::cout << "B BULLET" << std::endl;
        }
        if (fixtureAData->getCollisionObjectType() == COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE::ENEMY) {
            std::cout << "A ENEMY" << std::endl;
        }
        if (fixtureBData->getCollisionObjectType() == COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE::ENEMY) {
            std::cout << "B ENEMY" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "----------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

}

For some reason, the casting works for the Bullet class but not for the Enemy class. I think it returns a `nullptr`. So I know one of the colliding bodies is a bullet, but I can't tell what the second body is.

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong with the `static_cast` calls or it might be because the EnemySquare class is twice removed from the Entity class? or I could be doing something wrong in the Box2D code. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi there! Regarding the `static_cast`s Have a look [type casting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_casting_operators.htm). I have a feeling it should be `reinterpret_cast` instead.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for the suggestion, unfortunately still no luck. I'll keep looking into `reinterpret_cast` though, feels like that's a good solution I just maybe need to figure out how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `m_collisionObjectType` member variable for the `Enemy` derived class. Preferably to `COLLISION_OBJECT_TYPE::ENEMY`.

As the code appears now, it's only setting `m_collisionObjectType` in the code for the `Bullet` derived class. So the `Enemy` derived class instances are getting constructed with their `m_collisionObjectType` member variables uninitialized. I.e. the value out of the `getCollisionObjectType()` method could be whatever was in the memory location of `m_collisionObjectType` before it got used by the constructor.

Hope this helps!